# How to display images from Google Cloud Storage that start with gs:// in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, and I want to display some images that exist in Google Cloud Storage. The reference that I get is not an URL but a reference that starts with gs://. Here is what I have tried using Coil:

```
AsyncImage(
    modifier = Modifier.width(64.dp).height(64.dp),
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(url) // gs://...
        .build(),
    contentDescription = null
)
```

But I get:

```
Unable to fetch data.
```

How to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) SDK to access the storage bucket, and then use the [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) to download the actual images.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't there a simpler way for reading those images?

Comment: No, because those aren't just images. They're on a shared cloud service that requires authentication to use, and has an API to access

Comment: Can you please help me indicate something that I can follow to do that?

Comment: Actually, sorry, you can also use the Firebase Cloud Storage SDK, which may be a but simpler. It'll still require authentication and API access, though

Comment: Can you indicate me please where can I find the docs that explain how to read those gs://... images?

Comment: Let me try that, and I get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: As I see, the linked documentation requires to download the images locally, and I don't want that. I only want to display them, as I'm trying to do with Coil.

Comment: Sorry, but you won't be able to do that. Those aren't internet URLs -- they're URIs for for the cloud storage service. The only thing you can do it download them locally, and then have Coil display them from local storage